# How to set pickerView to the value selected previously?

Tags: ios, nsarray, uipickerview

I'm using picker view to select a value from an array, and saving it into a DB.
The next time that the user go into picker view "field" I want to set highlighted-selector to the value that was save to the DB.
How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method `-selectRow:inComponent:animated:` of `UIPickerView`:

```
// I suppose that you have such variables and one component
UIPickerView *pickerView;
NSArray *variants;

id userVariant = // get variant from db
NSUInteger row = [variants indexOfObject:userVariant];
if (row != NSNotFound) {
    [pickerView selectRow:[variants indexOfObject:userVariant] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```